# Foundation 5 off-canvas left-off-canvas-menu to show on default

Tags: zurb-foundation

This seems to be a simple thing but I can seem to find it anywhere under their documents. Currently the initial setting is hiding everything inside .left-off-canvas-menu, is there a setting where it can be set to show and only hide when .left-off-canvas-toggle is click?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Simply add the class 'move-right' to the 'off-canvas wrap'. That should display it as it would be active.

```
`<div class="off-canvas-wrap move-right"> 
    <div class="inner-wrap ">
```

About the exit case, you can use 'exit-off-canvas' class.

```
 <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
```